# Mqsql ef core Migration assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, mariadb

```
   services.AddDbContextPool<CPSContext>(
                    options => options.UseMySql(connectionString,

                        mySqlOptions =>
                        {
                            mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 17), ServerType.MariaDb)
                            .EnableRetryOnFailure(
                            maxRetryCount: 10,
                            maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                            errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                        }
                    ));
```

Acoove is my connection string..

I am getting below error

[image]

How to add migraton assemmbly to connection i am sin pamlio.ef core

```
b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(CPSContext).Assembly.FullName))
```

Initial My confi was

```
//services.AddDbContext<CPSContext>(options =>
            //options.UseMySQL(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(CPSContext).Assembly.FullName)));
```

Connection string:
"CPS": "server=195.22.106.22:3307;database=corepigm_standard;user=corepigm_admin;password=Db@dmin2;"

How to use port number in conncetion string.i a getting below erro

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrations assembly and similar is set on the options builder argument of the `UseMySql` call (named `mySqlOptions` in the code in question) similar to your initial configuration.

However the `ServerVersion` is not part of the options (hence the compile time error you are getting), but separate parameter of `UseMySql` between connection string and options builder, as can be seen in the commented code of the screenshot. Also it cannot be created using class constructors, but some static factory methods like `AutoDetect`, `Parse`, `Create` etc.

So the code matching your attempt is something like this

```cs
services.AddDbContextPool<CPSContext>(
    options => options.UseMySql(connectionString,
        ServerVersion.Create(new Version(5, 7, 17), ServerType.MariaDb),
        mySqlOptions =>
        {
            mySqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                maxRetryCount: 10,
                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                errorNumbersToAdd: null);

            mySqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(CPSContext).Assembly.FullName);
        }
    ));
```

Reference: [Configuration Options](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/wiki/Configuration-Options) topic of Pomelo provider.

Comment: THanks you very much...I need one more help how to use port number  in connection sstring updated in question.. i am getting error..Pls let me know..

Comment: Also i am getting dooes not contain definition for 'Create' message showing

Comment: It might  differ between versions. My answer is based on [6.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/6.0.1), you can check what static methods of `ServerVersion` class are available in your version. Also could try some direct constructors like `new MariaDbServerVersion(...)` instead.

Comment: What about connection string, it is different question, please remove the "update" and post it as separate question. Most likely you need to find the documentation of the MySql connection strings.

Comment: Thnks ...i wil update to 6..Port no issue soloved...Thanks a lot